# What "driving forces" have being introduced for human kind during history?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, terminology

AMAIK:

1. [Freud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libido) cites **libido** as the driving force of human being (the underlying part of **id**)
2. [Nietzsche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power) introduced **Will to power** as the driving force behind human actions
3. And [here](http://voices.yahoo.com/pain-pleasure-driving-force-all-human-behavior-5925334.html), **pain & pleasure** is defined to be the main driving force

Do we have other **driving forces** defined for human actions during history? What are they?

Comment: Marx introduced economics. Hegel the evolution of the world-spirit.

Comment: Spinoza's *conatus*, Darwin's logic of mutation and proliferation...

Comment: In one respect, we could say reason for both Kant and Hegel (for Hegel, the Absolute = necessity = Spirit = world-spirit)

Comment: For Plato, the desire for the forms. For Aristotle, the desire for God as the absolute telos of all things. Same for Augustine and Aquinas but now with the Christian God.

Comment: Buddhism introduced [Karma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma) (I think).

Comment: There is only one driving force - curiosity/creativity. Other forces are NOT driving they are steering forces. Without creativity modern politicians will be dividing icebergs to hunt and traders of Wallstreet will be selling mammoths.

Answer (score 1):

Kierkegaard's *Will To Meaning*, which was developed into Logotherapy by [Viktor Frankl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logotherapy).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer. Due to the passing 50 years between Kierkegaard's death and Frankl's birth, it's logically impossible that Frankl anticipated the Will to Meaning. If you wanted to express something else, please feel free to do so, as it currently stands, your answer isn't sufficiently elaborated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by will to meaning? There is no such Kierkegaard text. I think its more a retrospective interpretation (and a wrong one at that).

Comment: @virmaior *The Will to Meaning* is one of Victor Frankl's books. I've never heard it mentioned before that his system was based on Kierkegaard's earlier work, though. So I think the answer (current version) is wrong on at least one and maybe two counts.

Answer (score 1):

As regards point 1: "Freud cites libido as the driving force", [Freud separates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive#cite_ref-19) libido from the will to power:

> libido has the task of making the destroying instinct innocuous, and it fulfils the task by diverting that instinct to a great extent outwards. ... The instinct is then called the destructive instinct, the instinct for mastery, or the will to power.

It is this "instinct for mastery" that Derrida focuses on in "To Speculate--On Freud" casting it as Life Drive.  The gist is that the death drive and the life drive are two sides of the same coin.  For instance, the drive to master one's environment can transform into aggressive warfare.  (It was the aftermath of WWI that caused Freud to think of the death drive.)  On another scale, problem-solving tenacity can exhibit pathologically as repetition compulsion, (same [ref.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive#cite_ref-7)).

Comment: Would you be willing to articulate this answer a bit more? It sounds very interesting, but right now it's mostly a tease. :-)

Comment: I will post a reference here next time I get onto this very interesting topic.  In the meantime, here is quote from Derrida's [Resistances of Psychoanalysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Resistances_of_Psychoanalysis.html?id=-OxfQgAACAAJ) in which he focuses on a 'philolytic' type of repetition compulsion: ['_Excerpt_'](http://www.windmills.freeserve.co.uk/resistance.htm). An elusive form of problem solving, or rather, problem destruction.